# my android services are not stopping even after I broadcast and destroy it

Tags: android

```
                sendBroadcast(intent2);
                stopSelf();
```

Any idea how to stop this..Because it is making a REST call even after it stopping...

Comment: it is already tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this once,hope it helps

```
 stopService(intent2).
```

or see this link once [starting and stoping services](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/use-of-services/)